# Is it correct to state the decision problem Clique can be solved in time $O(\min(n^kk^2, 2^{n/4}))$?

Tags: time-complexity, clique

With the decision problem Clique, I mean:

Given a graph $G$, does $G$ admit a clique of size at least $k$?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), one finds that the brute force algorithm of testing all possible subsets of size $k$ results in a complexity of $O(n^kk^2)$. On the other hand, Wikipedia also states that a maximum size clique can be obtained in time $O(2^{n/4})$.

It seems to me that these complexities are incomparable, meaning that in some cases the former would outperform the latter and vice versa. Would it thus be correct to state that Clique can be solved in time $O(\min(n^kk^2, 2^{n/4}))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just compute which is the smallest between $n^kk^2$ and $2^{n/4}$ and run the corresponding algorithm.

Alternatively, you could run both algorithms in parallel (alternating one step of each) and stop when one finishes.